# Javascript function don't run at once

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, file-upload

I've some function javascript to check loaded file with FileUpload Control

```
 <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        function CheckFileBeforeUpdate() 
        {
            var filePath = document.getElementById('<%= this.upFile.ClientID %>').value;
            var validExtension = 'xml';
            var ext = filePath.substring(filePath.lastIndexOf('.') + 1).toLowerCase();
            if (ext == validExtension) return true;
            alert('The file extension ' + ext.toUpperCase() + ' is not allowed!');
            return false;
        }
    </script>
```

and it's called with Button: OnClientClick="return CheckFileBeforeUpdate();

```
<asp:Button ID="LoginButton" runat="server" CommandName="Login" Text="Log In" 
           onclick="LoginButton_Click" OnClientClick="return CheckFileBeforeUpdate();" />
```

So there's unusual situation:
I choose appropiate file, click Login...and it goes on to next functions despite inadequate extension.

Otherwise if I e.g. click FileUpload, but select no file. 
Next time I choose some file (even with bad extension) and then function run (shows alert).

Why there's sth like blockade? What can I do to change CheckFileBeforeUpdate() runs everytime?

**EDIT**
if I select no file there's show alert("Select file to log in"); of course. And then is lock release

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function CheckFileBeforeUpdate() 
    {
        var filePath = document.getElementById('<%= this.upFile.ClientID %>').value;
        var popupWindow = document.getElementById('<%= this.popupWin.ClientID %>').value;
        if (filePath.length < 1) {
            alert("Select file to log in");
            return false;
        }
        var validExtension = 'xml';
        var ext = filePath.substring(filePath.lastIndexOf('.') + 1).toLowerCase();
        if (ext == validExtension) return true;
        alert('The file extension ' + ext.toUpperCase() + ' is not allowed!');
        return false;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Please load it into firefox, look in the console. If there is an error, IE will continue the next statement. Fx will not

Comment: Your code is working for me in Firefox. Can you edit the question and include the full path of the file you are trying to select that has an invalid extension? Can you be sure there are no javascript errors occurring (see the first comment)?

Comment: How your code handles sitution, when no file is selected ? Won't it throw exception?

Comment: 2 situations:
1: select no file -> Log in -> validation run correct (shows alert) -> then every next chosen file is checking. 
2: select bad file -> validations don't run (program goes to next functions)

Comment: Log in -> validation run correct (shows alert) - but in code alert is shown if the extension is not correct. Am I missing something?

Comment: I edited my first post - add entire javascript function. If I select no file it shows first alert of course. But problem's not here. Why second alert don't run at first time?

Comment: The code you posted works in IE 8 and in Firefox 3.6 (I tested).  I think you need to supply some more information.  What browser are you using for test?  Did you try in Firefox with the Error Console up so you could see if there were any other errors occurring?  What is the exact filename you are selecting (in case there is something weird going on with the substring function)?

Comment: Yeah :) Firefox + Error Console are great :) There was error with this line: var popupWindow = document.getElementById('<%= this.popupWin.ClientID %>').value; I don't know why, but at first time it can find this control -> was error -> function break (is it normal behaviour in javascript?) When I comment this line everything works great :) But why it can't find this popupWin at once?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based solely on the question and the comments, the obvious answer is to just remove this line:

```
var popupWindow = document.getElementById('<%= this.popupWin.ClientID %>').value;
```

The value of popupWindow is not used anywhere in the posted code, so it appears that line is not necessary.

EDIT:

Based on the comments, I looked up the control.  See [this link](http://www.eeeksoft.net/files/popuptest/default.aspx).  I think the problem here is that this control is meant to be displayed after a postback or a page load, not from javascript.  Since I don't have the control I can't be certain, but if this control needs to be displayed on the client using Javascript before a postback occurs, then try viewing the source of the rendered page and see if you can find the HTML that represents the popup.  Hopefully it's in a div that has the popupWin.ClientID value set as the id.  If that is the case, then you can use this javascript to get a reference to it:

```
var popupWindow = document.getElementById('<%= this.popupWin.ClientID %>'); //omit the .value
```

You can then use your favorite code to display the popupWindow div.  I won't include that code here because if you're not using something like jQuery the correct answer is rather long if you want it to work in all browsers.

Personally, I would just use alert() and skip this control.  It's simpler and more likely to work across all browsers.

Comment: Full implementation CheckFileBeforeUpdate() is in first post. This is a control from external dll - more like messageBox in WindowsForms. Here can replace standard alert() window. But as we can see - not always :P some modifications are necessary

Comment: In the implementation of CheckFileBeforeUpdate() you posted, you don't need to get a reference to "popupWin" because you don't use "popupWin" anywhere else in the code.  Are you trying to use "popupWin" instead of alert?

Comment: In version before changes popupWin was using. Now I throw it, but yes - I'm trying use it instead of alert. Initialization this control is in codebehind.

Comment: OK, so what I'm trying to say is that there's not enough information here to tell you what going wrong, because we can't see how you're trying to use popupWin. =] Is popupWin a third party control?  Can you give us the name?

Comment: It's some external control. EeekSoft.Web.PopupWin.dll

Answer (score 1):

you can just do it with asp validators:

```
<asp:FileUpload ID="fu1" runat="server" />
<asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="req" runat="server"
   ErrorMessage="Select file" ControlToValidate="fu1" />
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator ID="rgx" runat="server"
   ErrorMessage="Extension not allowed" ControlToValidate="fu1"
   ValidationExpression=".*\.[xX][mM][lL]" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var validFilesTypes = ["bmp", "gif", "png", "jpg", "jpeg", "doc", "docx", "xls", "xlsx", "rar", "zip", "txt", "pdf"];

    function CheckExtension(file) {
        /*global document: false */
        var filePath = file.value;
        var ext = filePath.substring(filePath.lastIndexOf('.') + 1).toLowerCase();
        var isValidFile = false;

        for (var i = 0; i < validFilesTypes.length; i++) {
            if (ext == validFilesTypes[i]) {
                isValidFile = true;
                break;
            }
        }

        if (!isValidFile) {
            file.value = null;
            alert("Invalid File. Valid extensions are:\n\n" + validFilesTypes.join(", "));
        }

        return isValidFile;
    }
</script>
```

Comment: add javascript to tags